# How to call a class from onClick Java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am new to Java, coming from PHP. This may be a novice problem, but I am unable to figure it out via Google.  I have tried looking at tutorials, etc..  This is the point I have reached.  I think I am very close.  In the beginning, the code inside of `MyTask` was located inside the `onClick` section.  But I was getting a thread issue, which I understand.  It is trying to do too much on the main thread. So I learned about `AsyncTask` and tried to incorporate it.  I was getting help from one person, and they could only get me to this point. His first attempt to help left the `onClick` empty, and `MyTask` executed `onCreate`.  That is not what I needed.  I need to execute `MyTask` from `onClick`.  To fix that, he suggested adding the

```
myTask = new MyTask();
myTask.execute();
```

and the

```
MyTask myTask;
```

to the inside `onClick`.

But Eclipse says there are problems with that.  It wants to either create variables or other suggestions.  The problem is that when I incorporate those suggestions, Eclipse is never satisfied and keeps saying there are more problems.

Can anyone tell me how to call `MyTask` from inside the `onClick` without Eclipse objecting it?  As I said, I am a novice, and generalities are sometimes lost on me.  If you have an answer, would it be okay to ask that you be as specific as possible?  I have posted the code below.  Thank you for helping me out here.  And if you need anymore info to answer this, let me know and I will get you the answers.

```
package com.exmple.myapp;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.exmple.myapp.LoginActivity.MyTask;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputUser;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;


// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    myTask = new MyTask();
    myTask.execute();
    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            MyTask myTask;

        } 


            // Link to Register Screen
            /**       btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        **/
    }); 
 }       

//*** Move out MyTask
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    String user = inputUser.getText().toString();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(user, password);
        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Store user details in SQLite Database
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    // Clear all previous data in database
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                    // Launch Dashboard Screen
                    Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GD_Calc.class);

                    // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                    dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(dashboard);

                    // Close Login Screen
                    finish();
                }else{
                    // Error in login
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        return null;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Eclipse says there are problems with that" Please post the *exact* error messages.

Comment: I didn't see your response until now.  Eclipse flags the line with a red flag and I can't run the app until I fix it.  The red flag is in the onCreate section and says "Mytask cannot be resolved to a type".  This specific error is from my code where I am trying to incorporate the suggestions from @drewmore below. When I hover over the red underlined section I get the suggestions Eclipse thinks need to be done to fix the problem.  To get a list of those options, please refer to my response to the answer below.  There are no log errors, can't run.

Comment: Note that `Mytask` is **not** the same thing as `MyTask`. Java is case-sensitive. You need to make sure that the name of your class exactly matches the type in your variable declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing a new object of class `MyTask` properly. Here is how to do it:

`MyTask mt = new MyTask()`

`MyTask` is a class, in order to utilize it, you have to create a new instance of it. You do so by calling `{ClassName} {instanceName} = new {ClassName(parameters defined by a constructor of the class ClassName)}`. This is true with regard to creating objects of all kinds in java.

Welcome to object-oriented programming in Java :)

Comment: Okay, after trying your suggestion it reminded me that I have been here before.  I am getting an error on (using your suggestion) the 'Mytask' section.  Eclipse gives me 8 suggestions ranging from create a new class Mytask, or an enum or an interface.....  What am I doing wrong here.  I do understand what your are suggesting.  I think I am missing something else.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention your name so you will be notified of my response.  Thanks for your help so far guys.  @drewmore

Comment: Bumping..can somebody expand on this answer based on my response?

Comment: @jj.amoniit I edited this answer to fix an error in the suggestion. For further assistance, I suggest that you read up on creating objects in Java.

Comment: Also, when you call `MyTask myTask` in the onClickListener, you're creating a new instance of myTask (without instantiating it), which I don't think is what you want to do. You want to call `myTask = new MyTask();` and `myTask.execute();` above the onClickListener, as you have done, but you need to add the `final` keyword before the declaration (so `final MyTask myTask = new myTask();`) so that you can reference that object inside the onClickListener (which is actually a separate inner class). Then, inside the listener, you can simply call `myTask.[method you want to call]`.